# How to set a default raster style?

Tags: qgis

Most of my layers in Qgis are shapefiles but I have some raster data which is terrain relief shadings that are GeoTIFFs.

In order to save a lot of time with the default colour and density that Qgis sets, I am trying to find out if there is some way I can set the colour and transparency all at once.

Simply put I want a colour (or rendertype) of singleband grey and a global transparency of 80% to be able to be applied all at once. I tried to set up a style for this but some of this information is not saved into the style.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you save a project that has a raster with transparency the transparency doesn't get saved? I've noticed that too. One way round this is to overlay the hillshade raster with a large vector polygon and set its fill to white, then adjust the transparency of the polygon fill to get the hillshade looking right. Then add your vector layers on top of this. The transparency settings of the vector polygon layer will saved when you save the project. N.

Comment: A behavior like this (transparency settings not saved) should be reported as a bug.

Comment: It's a known problem,see http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4953. Said to have been fixed in Master, but I haven't checked this. N.

Comment: No, what I am looking at is a way of saving the transparency into a style, so that I can apply that style to other rasters.

Comment: If saving the layer style as a *.qml file doesn't work I don't know what to suggest. Except for upgrading to Master that is, but there might be good reasons why you don't want to do this.

Comment: If you go to the style page, transparency is not part of the style of the layer.

Comment: OK. We'll close this off, because I figured out how to resolve this in 1.9, because it displays the images differently and I don't need to set the transparency at all.